# Where Merging two entities falls in Restful way

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, restful-architecture

I have to do following:

Merge Source Entity to Target Entity. Both Source and Target Entity are of same type. So, end result would be both Source and Target would merge to one Target entity so that all the properties of Target will remain as it is, but if any of the property in Target is not there, it will be copied from Source.

In the end, source would be deleted.

My question is, in Restful way where should this fall - POST / PUT / DELETE and why?

Or, it will be multiple operations - PUT / POST followed by DELETE?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one call. Assuming the unique id for the target remains the same in the new entity, just allow:

```
POST /entities/{targetEntityId}
{
    "mergeFrom": "/entities/{sourceEntityId}
}
```

POST allows side effects, so you may choose to do the delete as part of this call. Alternately, you may choose to allow the client to determine whether or not the source gets deleted by requiring them to call `DELETE /entities/{sourceEntityId}` after the POST.

To use PUT, you'd need the client to do the merge and include all the values, which is presumably undesirable.